# Tip Calculator not giving Total Amount

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a tip calculator but I'm having trouble creating a variable that will give me the total amount of the bill. Below is the code, any suggestions?

```
    function tipCalculate (slider, bill){
  var tip = document.getElementById('tipamount');
  var slideval = document.getElementById('slideval');
  var bill = document.getElementById(bill).value;
  var prcnt = slider * .01;
  var total = Number(bill) + tip;

  if (bill == null || bill == '') {
    tip.innerHTML = 'Please enter an amount';
    return false;
  }
  if(isNaN(bill)) {
    tip.innerHTML = 'Please enter a number';
    return false;
  }
  if(bill >= 0){
    tip.innerHTML = '$' + (bill * prcnt) .toFixed(2);
  slideval.innerHTML = slider + '%';
  }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to add a DOM element (`tip`) to a number (`Number(bill)`). That can't work.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Also you assume slideval is a number but then you insert a string into it. You may want to consider using inputs and their value properties instead of innerHTML. innerHTML should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Line 6 is your problem. `tip` is a dom element and you are trying to add it to a value accessed in the dom i.e bill's value;

This line is not correct:

```
 var total = Number(bill) + tip;
```